# Allow user to change div text through textbox in a side-panel (Customize components)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

So I have this block of code that should take the value from a textbox I have made called 'changeTitle' and when I press enter it should then display in the selected div class called "kpiTitle" what am I missing here? I can't get my head around it.

```
 **function changeTitle()
    { 
        *var titleClass = document.getElementsByClassName("changeTitle");*
        var newTitle = nameElement.value;
        document.getElementByClassName("KpiTitle").innerHTML += newTitle;
    }
    {
        // Update KPI title
        $(document).bind('keypress', function (changeTitle) {
            if (changeTitle.keyCode == 13) {
                $('#changeTitle').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    };**
```

---

Comment: This is how my textbox is created: "changeTitle": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "title": "changeTitle",
                        "options": {
                            "collapsed": false
                        },
                        "properties": {
                            "changeTitle": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "title": "changeTitle",
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }

Comment: it should be _document.getElementsByClassName("KpiTitle")[0].innerHTML_
You are missing an s and that method returns an array.